# Errors when trying to deploy react-app to Vercel (Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1)

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, vercel

I've been trying to deploy my create-react-app to vercel but keep getting the following error. Everything works locally and even builds with no errors. How can I fix it? I already tried to get variables on vercel project settings and nothing.

I build with `npm run build` and do nothing with Yarn, so I don't get it.

```
14:50:48    511[1/4] Resolving packages                                                                                 
14:50:49    609[2/4] Fetching packages                                                                                  
14:51:06    414info fsevents@2  3   2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module                                                                            
14:51:06    414info "fsevents@2 3   2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check  Excluding it from installation                                                                     
14:51:06    431info fsevents@1  2   13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module                                                                           
14:51:06    431info "fsevents@1 2   13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check     Excluding it from installation                                                                     
14:51:06    444[3/4] Linking dependencies                                                                                   
14:51:06    446warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12   8   3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7  21  4"                                                                  
14:51:06    447warning " > react-lottie@1   2   3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0  14  7 || ^15    0   0 || ^16    0   0"                                                  
14:51:06    451warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3    20  0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2    8   0 || >= 3   2   0-dev || >= 3   3   0-dev || >= 3   4   0-dev || >= 3   5   0-dev || >= 3   6   0-dev || >= 3   6   0-beta || >= 3  7   0-dev || >= 3   7   0-beta" 
14:51:20    599[4/4] Building fresh packages                                                                                    
14:51:21    325success Saved lockfile                                                                                   
14:51:21    331Done in 32   90s                                                                             
14:51:21    551Running "yarn run build"                                                                                 
14:51:21    736yarn run v1  22  10                                                                          
14:51:21    764$ CI=false && react-scripts build                                                                                    
14:51:23    059Creating an optimized production build                                                                                   
14:51:23    841Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated    Please run:                                                                                
14:51:23    842npx browserslist@latest --update-db                                                                                  
14:51:23    842                                                                                 
14:51:23    842Why you should do it regularly:                                                                                  
14:51:23    842https://github   com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating                                                                                
14:51:26    498Failed to compile                                                                                    
14:51:26    498                                                                                 
14:51:26    502 /src/components/header/Banner   js                                                                          
14:51:26    502Cannot find file 'C:/Users/gabri/OneDrive/Documentos/React/portifolio/src/assets/img/profile/eu  png' in '   /src/components/header'                                                                         
14:51:26    502                                                                                 
14:51:26    503                                                                                 
14:51:26    526 error Command failed with exit code                                                                                 
14:51:26    526 info Visit https://yarnpkg  com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command                                                                                
14:51:26    542 Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "portifolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false && react-scripts build",  
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

> Cannot find file
> 'C:/Users/gabri/OneDrive/Documentos/React/portifolio/src/assets/img/profile/eu
> png' in '   /src/components/header'

Check that you're referencing this file properly in your header component.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing CI false in package.json
In Vercel when you choose your Project from GitHub and in **Configure Project** Box you can add Environment Variable as *Name* is `CI` and *VALUE* is `false`
then Deploy it, I assume it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, you have to check the version of node you are using.
Node version 18 gives you that error, maybe you are using node v16. In my case I was using version 16.
The solution for me was the following:
In package.json

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16"
},
```